# Not able to communicate with PayPal server

Tags: ios, paypal

**Update:** `hideCreditCardButton` has no role in this issue, it was just a coincident that when I tried it w/o credit card it worked for me but thats not the case anymore.I does work but only 20-30% of the time.

I am using PayPal iOS SDK 1.4.6. if I use `paymentViewController.hideCreditCardButton = YES;` it works fine but if I set this to `paymentViewController.hideCreditCardButton = NO;` I get the server error (ref. to image).

[image]

here's my code:

```
- (void)paypalPayment {

// Create a PayPalPayment
float paypalPrice =[youPay floatValue];
NSString* currencyCode = appDelegate.countryCurrency;
if ([currencyCode isEqual: @"INR"]) {
    float new = [[[ExchangeRate sharedManager]getExchangeRate:@"INR" toCurrency:@"USD"]
 floatValue];
    paypalPrice = paypalPrice*new;
}


PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",paypalPrice]];
payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
payment.shortDescription = @"Total Order";

[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentProduction];

// Provide a payerId that uniquely identifies a user within the scope of your system,
// such as an email address or user ID.
NSString *aPayerId = @"abc@msronline.in";

PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;
paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] 
initWithClientId:kPayPalClientId
receiverEmail:kPayPalReceiverEmail
                              payerId:aPayerId
                              payment:payment
                              delegate:self];
paymentViewController.languageOrLocale = @"en";
 paymentViewController.hideCreditCardButton = NO;
[self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dave from PayPal here.

That's indeed weird. You're getting this as soon as you present the viewcontroller? Is it still happening today?

From your screenshot, it looks like the SDK is still trying to get an initial connection with the PayPal server. At this early stage, the setting of `hideCreditCardButton` shouldn't yet affect anything.

You are using the Client ID that's designated for Production (as opposed to the Client ID designated for Sandbox), right?

Do you see anything helpful in the console log?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for replying. You are right `hideCreditCardButton` is not affecting it, maybe there's something else, it was just a coincident that when I tried it w/o credit card it worked for me but thats not the case anymore. It works 3-4 times out of 10 times.

Comment: I'm using Client ID that's designated for Production and I don't see anything in the console. P.S: I live in India, does this have to do anything with that?

Comment: It could be that there is simply some connectivity problem (perhaps between an Indian PayPal server and another PayPal server), or some other problem isolated to a server that you are interacting with. You might need to contact PayPal developer support to track this down.

Answer (score 0):

- I have same issue and solved by change `kPayPalReceiverEmail`.
- If you use same email as `kPayPalReceiverEmail` to login in paypal to send payment than this error comes.
- I just change `kPayPalReceiverEmail` email to another one and I get successful response from paypal server.

It may help you

Comment: As far as I know `kPayPalReceiverEmail` should be the one your PayPal developer account is associated with, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is not must required.. You can use any other too.. Currently i am using other than paypal developer account..

Comment: "kPayPalReceiverEmail should be the one your PayPal developer account is associated with" -- yes, this is the official recommendation. As Rahul notes, though, you should not also use this same email address as the pay*er*'s address that logs into the SDK.

Comment: Thanks @DaveGoldman . And I am hoping that you guys will overcome on this bug in your next sdk updates.