# There is an issue while communicating with the PayPal servers in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using `Paypal SandBox Environment`. When I am opening `Paypal` from device i am getting this error:

> Request has failed with error: pp_service_error_json_parse_error - System error. Please try again later. (403) | Details: (
>           {
>           "ns_error" = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 \"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.\" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}";
>       }
>   ).

check Screenshot

[image]

Here is My code

```
        _payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];

    _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;
#else
    _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = NO;
#endif
    _payPalConfig.merchantName = @"";
    _payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
    _payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
    _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];
    _payPalConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption = PayPalShippingAddressOptionPayPal;
    self.environment = PayPalEnvironmentSandbox;
    nslog(@"PayPal iOS SDK version: %@", [PayPalMobile libraryVersion]);





    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    // Preconnect to PayPal early

    [self setPayPalEnvironment:self.environment];
}



    - (void)setPayPalEnvironment:(NSString *)environment
    {
    self.environment = environment;

    [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentSandbox:PAYPAL_CLIENT_KEY}];
    [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:environment];
}
```

I am not getting why i am getting error.
Anyone is having solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21721578/6271729 can you please check this.

Comment: @Niharika Thanks for response.

Comment: @Niharika i solve issue when i chang  environment to PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork for testing purpose